# Python dataframe value did not change at all

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanna change specific cell value in dataframe type.
When i specific string type entered in the index, the specific cell value is changed.
But, i enter string variable in the index, they didn't change at all.

For example,

```
if target in self.confusion_mat.index:
        if prediction in self.confusion_mat.columns:
          self.confusion_mat.loc[target, prediction] = 99
          self.confusion_mat.loc['abnormaluterinebleeding', 'abnormaluterinebleeding'] = 99
print(self.confusion_mat)
```

and result is below

```
sdconfusion mat size =  (663, 663)
depression depression
=================!!!!!===============
                           abnormaluterinebleeding  ...  zollinger ellisonsyndrome
abnormaluterinebleeding                         99  ...                          0
abortion                                         0  ...                          0
acetaminophenoverdose                            0  ...                          0
aciallipoatrophy                                 0  ...                          0
acialwrinkles                                    0  ...                          0
...                                            ...  ...                        ...
women oxybutynin                                 0  ...                          0
xerostomia                                       0  ...                          0
yellowfeverprophylaxis                           0  ...                          0
zenshoulde                                       0  ...                          0
zollinger ellisonsyndrome                        0  ...                          0

[663 rows x 663 columns]
```

i don't know why statement 'self.confusion_mat['cough', 'cough'] = 99' change the cell value, but 'self.confusion_mat[target, prediction] = 99' when target = 'cough' prediction = 'cough' does not change
at all cell value.

is there any mistake in my conception?

the same test code is below

```
target_name = 'condition3'
target_label = df_test[target_name].unique()
target_label.sort()
confusion_mat = pd.DataFrame(index=target_label, columns=target_label)
confusion_mat = confusion_mat.fillna(0)
print(confusion_mat)

for index in range(0, 10):
  example = df_train.iloc[index]
  tmp_result = predictConditionSum(lemlem(example['review']))
  tmp_result = sorted(tmp_result.items(), key = lambda item : item[1], reverse=True)

  if (len(tmp_result) == 0):
    continue
  
  prediction = tmp_result[0][0]
  target = example[target_name]

  confusion_mat.loc[target, prediction] = 99
confusion_mat.loc['abnormaluterinebleeding','abnormaluterinebleeding'] = 99
print(confusion_mat)

--------------------------------result---------------------------------------

                           abnormaluterinebleeding  ...  zollinger ellisonsyndrome
abnormaluterinebleeding                          0  ...                          0
abortion                                         0  ...                          0
acetaminophenoverdose                            0  ...                          0
aciallipoatrophy                                 0  ...                          0
acialwrinkles                                    0  ...                          0
...                                            ...  ...                            ...
    women oxybutynin                                 0  ...                          0
xerostomia                                       0  ...                          0
yellowfeverprophylaxis                           0  ...                          0
zenshoulde                                       0  ...                          0
zollinger ellisonsyndrome                        0  ...                          0

[663 rows x 663 columns]
                       abnormaluterinebleeding  ...  zollinger     ellisonsyndrome
abnormaluterinebleeding                         99  ...                          0
abortion                                         0  ...                          0
acetaminophenoverdose                            0  ...                          0
aciallipoatrophy                                 0  ...                          0
acialwrinkles                                    0  ...                          0
...                                            ...  ...                            ...
    women oxybutynin                                 0  ...                          0
xerostomia                                       0  ...                          0
yellowfeverprophylaxis                           0  ...                          0
zenshoulde                                       0  ...                          0
zollinger ellisonsyndrome                        0  ...                          0

[663 rows x 663 columns]
```

Comment: There a high chance that `target` and `prediction` variable does not have proper values. Check for extra spaces or other characters. Also check `type(target)` and `type(prediction)`

Comment: thanks for reply,  but  i already check the type(both are str class), and check boolean for "if target in confusion_mat.index" and "if prediction in confusion_mat.columns" which return true....

Comment: hmm... i just change the logic, and find the way by iloc(). Anyway thanks to reply bro